# Auto-renewing subscription doesn't renew

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

When purchasing auto-renewable subscriptions in the AppStore sandbox, the subscriptions don't automatically renew and terminate after the first period.

I don't know why, but this was working before. What I do is run a cron every few minutes that revalidates the stored receipt and fetches the `latest_receipt_info.expires_date_ms` with the biggest timestamp value.

According to Apple's documentation 1 month subscriptions should renew 5 times every 5 minutes.

Is the sandbox just flaky or is this expected behavior?

**Update**

I created a new sandbox user and now it renews again correctly. What did I miss?

Comment: do you get the same problem with new sandbox user?

Comment: Created a new user and now it renews again correctly. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reuse the same sandbox user after the ends of the 5 renewals periods, you will need to create a new one to test again. They can only used for one test cycle.